# Annotation processors with jar files

Tags: android, annotations, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I have a problem with realm-annotations-processor-3.2.1.jar. This is really allocated in libs folder project, but when I am running the application Android Studio show this message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>   Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - realm-annotations-processor-3.2.1.jar (realm-annotations-processor-3.2.1.jar)
>     Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

What is the problem? How can I add annotationProcessor configuration to a external jar file? This is an important part of my build.gradle file:

```
compile(name: 'realm-android-library-3.2.1', ext: 'aar')
compile files('libs/realm-annotations-3.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/realm-annotations-processor-3.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/realm-transformer-3.2.1.jar')
```

Can anybody help me?

Regards

Comment: Are you adding the dependencies to Realm manually? you should use the Realm plugin instead which is setting correctly the `annotationProcessor` https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/dc56fd7091d707920b3471f5ac57661994b8d928/CHANGELOG.md#220-2016-11-12